# Flutter: BoxFit.scaleDown but set the text at its start of the container

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

```
 Container(
    width: 200,
    color: Colors.blue,
    child: FittedBox(
      fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
      child: Text(
        'hiiiiii',
        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

I have this widget that looks like

[image]

But, I want to set it to the beginning of the container like when I do not use `FittedBox` widget.

[image]

Is there any way that I can use `FittedBox's BoxFit.scaleDown` and put the text in the beginning?

Comment: I'm on a phone. Have you checked the `textAlign` property On the Text? Set `textAlign:  TextAlign.start`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Container(
   alignment : Alignment.leftCenter, //add alignment to fitted box
    width: 200,
    color: Colors.blue,
    child: FittedBox(
      fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
      child: Text(
        'hiiiiii',
        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
        textAlign: TextAlign.start //add left align to text content too 
      ),
    ),
  ),
```